# increase/decrease a number in Objective-C iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

Im new in xcode and programming for iOS.
I have follow this tutorial:
http://www.thetutorialblog.com/cocoa-objective-c/creating-a-basic-ipad-application/

I got it working with one "- button", one label and one "+ button".
But i want multiple of those, i have add the tutorial code and copy it like this:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *currentNumber2;

-(IBAction)incrementNumber2:(id)sender2;
-(IBAction)decrementNumber2:(id)sender2;


-(IBAction)incrementNumber2:(id)sender2 {
    number++;
    [currentNumber2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];
}


-(IBAction)decrementNumber2:(id)sender2 {
    number--;
    [currentNumber2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];
}
```

But when I press the first + button, it count up +1 in first label, then when I press the second + button, it continue counting from first button in label2 so it put in 2. Understand?

Comment: Are there more than button and more than one label?

Comment: In that case you need more than one instance variable (or more than one model object; this is a key concept in Object-Oriented programming. That instance of `number` is shared across all method calls on that object.

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: yes, i have added - button, label, + button and connected those from xib to incrementNumber2 and decrementNumber2 and label2 connected to  *currentNumber2.

Comment: i want multiple labels that i want to inc and dec every label.

Comment: @ctrahey Post that as an answer

Comment: @ctrahey , i tried this:


int number2 = 0;
-(IBAction)incrementNumber2:(id)sender2 {
 number++;
 [currentNumber2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number2]];
}

-(IBAction)decrementNumber2:(id)sender2 {
 number--;
 [currentNumber2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number2]];
}

Now the second buttons not work, not that simple?

Comment: Now it worked! 
I forgot to change number++; number--; to number2++; number2--;
Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quintessential behavior of object-oriented programming: that single instance of `number` is shared across every method call on that object. If you want to support multiple `number` instances, you have two choices: add more instance variables to your class and start adding more and more code as you make more instances, or simply spawn a new instance of your class.

Note that you will very quickly make a valuable realization: Sometimes the *modeled domain* has different *object requirements* than our application domain (i.e. you should be saying "But I shouldn't have to make more instances of my `UIViewController`!!", and you're right). This is the first step toward an architecture which iOS *deeply* supports: Model-View-Controller. Your Model, in this case `number`, should be decoupled from the controller, which should be capable of handling any quantity of them (not just as many as you happened to create ivars for).

It's a good path to be on :-)

Comment: Thank you very much @ctrahey !
As you say, I can add more and more code, but this app gonna end up with around 100 labels that i want to inc and dec and to add code for all this gonna take me unnecessary time. I dont know if I understand you what my second choice is. How do I spawn a new instace of my class? Is it "easy" to tell here or can you give me a tips for a tutorial?

Comment: That depends on how familiar you are with design patterns and if you have implemented MVC in other apps. For those starting out with Objective-C/Cocoa/iOS, my favorite resource is the Stanford CS193p lecure videos on iTunes U by Paul Hegarty, who was an engineer at NextStep when all this stuff was originally cooked up. One of the first few lectures is dedicated to the notion of MVC in iOS. http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10